# HTML textarea linebreak on clicking enter key in android keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am creating a webapp for android device using html5,javascript and css3. I have a screen which has a textarea. User can enter his comments in the textarea. On clicking the android enter/return key of keyboard, the cursor should move to next line in the textarea.

Any help on this feature ?

I tried many ways. like

```
  $('#reply').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    var data = $('#reply').val();
    logger.debug("data = " + data);
    $('#reply').text(data.replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
});
```

#reply is the id of my textarea.

No luck....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return key can be checked using this key code 13 and just append newline character to force user to write on newline:

```
 $("#reply").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
       event.preventDefault();
       var s = $(this).val();
       $(this).val(s+"\n");
      }     
 });
```

Comment: hmmm... for me, event.preventDefault() doesn't work on Chrome/Android but it works in non-mobile browsers.